# How to avoid type annotations with literal numbers and types based on them?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

In Typed Racket, if I have the following type and function:

```
(define-type A (U 'one 'two))
(define (f [a : A]) : A
  a)
```

Then the function call `(f 'one)` typechecks. However, if I use literal numbers as components of a union type like this:

```
(define-type B (U 1 2))
(define (g [b : B]) : B
  b)
```

Then `(g 2)` fails to typecheck with the type error:

```
Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: B
  given: Positive-Byte in: 2
```

However, `(g 1)` typechecks because `1` has it's own type, `One`.

I can solve the problem with `(g (ann 2 B))` (*or `(g #{2 :: B})`*), but this is awkward and cumbersome. Is this a fundamental limit of Typed Racket's handling of numeric types, or is there a way to make the explicit type annotation unnecessary?

Comment: `(g 2)` works fine for me (Racket 6.1.1).

Comment: Works for me on 6.1.1.2. Also back on 6.0 -- after rewriting to use separate `:`, `(: g (B -> B)) (define (g b) b)` -- because TR didn't provide its own `define` back then. Maybe your example here accidentally got simplified too much?

Comment: @GregHendershott - I was running 6.1.0.5 and it wasn't working, but your suggestion of rewriting to use `:` fixed it. I'm really curious why exactly `define` used to behave like that though.

Comment: @Jack I don't know. That question is probably best put to the Racket mailing list, or the #racket IRC channel, frequented by some of the Typed Racket developers.